# window.postMessage on iframe to communicate to webpage

Tags: javascript, iframe

I use, `window.postMessage` inside `iframe` to communicate with the current webpage like `localhost:8080`

the current webpage contain an iframe with a custom DOM

In my Iframe :

`window.postMessage('click', '*')`

In my webpage :

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
   if (e.message === 'click') { console.log('e', e) }
})
```

The current problem, is iframe not communicate the message to the parent, I know cross-origin problem but I'm always thinking postMessage it used to bypass this problem

I don't know why... my iframe is generating from localhost:9000

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window` in your iframe's context point's to the iframe's Window. You are posting a message to the iframe's content from the iframe's content.
What you want is to post a message to the `parent` context, so do

```
parent.postMessage(message, parents_origin);
```

Where `parents_origin` is the origin of the parent document *(or `"*"` if you want your iframe's doc work for any website embedding your iframe's page on their own website.)*